# Event(s) for opening the workbook AND worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for an elegant solution to trigger an event for opening the workbook as well as opening different worksheets. I don't need seperate operations for each worksheet: they all trigger the same method.

I know I can use the events `Workbook_Activate` / `Workbook_Open` and  `Workbook_SheetActivate` at the same time but I don't know if this is 'the official way' to do it. Perhaps there's a way to do this with one event.

I was also wondering if it is relevant in this matter where I put the code. I now have all the code inside "ThisWorkbook" and not in a "Module"...

Comment: You can capture Workbooks open and closing (on a global level rather than per each Workbook) with an Application level event. See this [class module example](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx) from Chip Pearson

Comment: There's no single event to do this, so `_Open` and `_SheetActive` would be the way to go. You can put the actual method which does the work in a regular module, and just call it from the workbook module event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have mentioned: there's no single event to do this. There might be workarounds, but I prefer just using _Open and _SheetActive in that case. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I developed a while ago to ensure that a report my managers use is always opened to the correct tab based on time of day.  I house this code in the "ThisWorkbook" module of my VBA.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'   Set The Office
Dim begin As String
Dim myNum As String
Dim myNum1 As String
Dim TheDate As String

'   Set Date
    TheDate = Format(DateTime.Now(), "mm-dd-yy")
    Sheets("MORNING").Range("H3").Value = TheDate
    Sheets("AFTERNOON").Range("G3").Value = TheDate
    'Sheets("EVENING").Range("G3").Value = TheDate

'   Select Sheet Based on Time of Day
    If Time >= 0.1 And Time < 0.5 Then
    Sheets("MORNING").Select
    Range("A53").Value = "Report completed by:"
    Range("C53").Value = Application.UserName
    Range("I53").Value = Date & " " & Time
    Range("B27").Select
    Call Populate 'Your next code
        ElseIf Time >= 0.5 And Time < 0.75 Then
        Sheets("AFTERNOON").Select
        Range("A54").Value = "Report completed by:"
        Range("C54").Value = Application.UserName
        Range("I54").Value = Date & " " & Time
        Range("C28").Select
        Call Populate 'Your next code

    End If

End Sub
```

Notice that I have also added code to auto sign the form output with the userid and update date and time.  I hope this helps.

Comment: A mistake.  It is the user name of the person who edited th epost.  My bad.